# How to pass XML Document objects around?

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

Is it possible to pass around an XML DOM Document to another Thread using an Intent?
I wonder if this is possible as I couldn't find anything about it on Google...

I use different XML Documents in my application all derived from a single Interface class. I want to create such a Document in, say, a Service & then pass it to a Thread or another Service to send it via a DatagramSocket. But I can't figure out how to properly do it... I guess it's possible to make the Documents Serializable, and then add them to the Intent I want to pass around... But is this a proper way to go or is it better to use another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass around an XML DOM Document to another Thread using an Intent?

First, you do not pass things to threads via `Intents`, unless that thread is the one managed by `IntentService`.

Second, you cannot put a DOM `Document` in an `Intent` extra.

> But is this a proper way to go or is it better to use another approach?

In your case, don't have two services. Combine them into a single service, and you do not have to worry about the problem.

Comment: I have only one service, which creates a Thread. It is to this Thread that I need to pass XML data. But I think I have another idea.. I'll make a Java representation of the XML data, and then make these parcelable. That way I can pass the data around ;)

Comment: @ThaMe90: "It is to this Thread that I need to pass XML data" -- if this is all in the same service, there is no `Intent`. Make the data available to the thread using the ordinary `Document` object, either when you start the thread, or via a `LinkedBlockingQueue` if you are creating a thread pool, or something.

Comment: I send stuff to my Thread by using a BroadcastReceiver, so it is done with Intents... So far it has worked, I only accept custom Actions when it comes to this receiver... I don't use a Thread pool at all...

Comment: @ThaMe90: You do not need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to talk to a thread within your `Service` from other code within that same `Service`. Just use ordinary Java, please.

Comment: I just don't see what you mean. The places from which I want to send stuff to the Thread don't have access to the Thread... only the Service has & I don't do much work there...

Comment: After a while (about a month or 2-3 ago), I decided to completely do it another way around. However, seeing my reactions to your post, I saw that I was being dumb. You were indeed correct about it all.. My apologies for my comments...